# how can i parse code from c#-6 to c#-5

Tags: c#

i have a c# project that is wrote in vs 2015 c# 6. there is two line that i', getting error :

```
public override bool Confirmed => true;
public override bool Responded { get; }
```

how can i parse it to c# 5?
thank you

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: Have you tried anything? I doubt it isn´t that difficult to write some working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first new C# 6 feature is called "Expression-bodied members". It translates to:

```
public override bool Confirmed { get { return true; } }
```

The second is "getter-only auto-properties". It translates to:

```
private readonly bool responded;
public override bool Responded { get { return responded; } }
```

You can also initialize them now:

```
public override bool Responded { get; } = false;
```

Comment: The second line is the same in C#5 and C#6.

Comment: @Steve It is not valid in C# 5

Comment: Huh, quite right. I guess I'm thinking of `get; private set;`

Comment: hi, your answer solved my problem and thanks for that, im getting another problem for "nameof(body)". what is "nameof"? and how can i parse it? - @Dennis_E

Comment: @siml nameof is also a new feature. It simply inserts the string "body", so just replace it with that.

Answer (score 5):

The line `public override bool Confirmed => true` is new syntactic sugar for C# 6 and is equivalent to:

```
public override bool Confirmed
{
    get { return true; }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear, this syntax is a bit bizzare. Thanks for explanation!

Comment: I tend to agree, it's certainly less verbose though.